# How google load balancer maintain consistency in routing?

Tags: deployment, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

I have two google cloud instances running on different regions (West and East). Each instances have their own database. I am using `Google Load balancer` to route the traffic based upon the client's `IP address` (This is what Google load balancer is doing internally on Network load balancing).

For example, Bob is requesting from the east region and `GLB` will route the request to east region node only. Similarly, Dave is requesting from the west region and `GLB` will route the request to west region node.

Scenarios:
1. Bob just sign up and a new entry added to the `East` region database.
2. Bob tries to fetch his profile but somehow request went to the `West` (Bob now using a VPN) region and there is no information available.

Is there a way that I can customize `GLB`? If yes, then I can solve this problem by applying consistency hashing on the load balancer (using userId as a hash function) which will make sure that the request coming from `Bob` will always go to `East` region.

Comment: In your story, what if the east region is down?  Are you saying that the west region couldn't service the request?

Comment: I have multiple containers running in `West` region. Somehow and hypothetically If all containers are down then it should serve to `West` region but I am worried about the request consistency and database consistency. I can't sync the data in every millisecond. It would be a bad architecture. I will sync at some point when load is down around 4 AM but what about the rest of day

Comment: Have you considered using one of Google's database as a service components that provide high volume and scalability such as BigTable and Cloud Spanner?  These assure ACID properties combined with high volumes / low latency without you having to concern yourself with the underlying infrastructure.  In your last post ... did you mean to say "West" twice or should one be West and the other East?

Comment: The same issue will be there. Let's say I am using `Big Table` in a distributed environment deployed in different regions. I still have to maintain data consistency.
 What you are suggesting is to put server-side code in a distributed platform and all server nodes are connecting with one separated server where `Big Table` database hosted. This is a very insufficient and not cost-efficient solution due to database locking mechanism

Answer (score 1):

You can use the HTTP Load Balancer options: Session Affinity and Client IP Affinity.

There are subtle issues with any method, read the documentation carefully. The biggest issue is for clients behind a NAT (airport, hotel, Starbucks, etc.). Their public IP address is the same for all clients behind the NAT, therefore all traffic will go to the same backend for Client IP based affinity. I recommend using cookies.

**Session affinity** uses Client IP or Generated Cookie to make traffic decisions. This can keep traffic routed to the same backend.

[Session Affinity](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-service#session_affinity)

**Client IP affinity** directs requests from the same client IP address to the same backend instance based on a hash of the client's IP address.

[Using Client IP Affinity](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-service#client_ip_affinity)